# How to avoid duplicate rows when inserting data in a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, datagridview, timer, serial-port, rfid

I am developing an application that reads RFID's in the serial port. I use a `timer` to keep scaning until the user clicks a button. 
When the scanner find a new RFID, I insert the info in a `DataGridView`, if the RFID is already in the `DataGridView` I paint the row with green color and if a RFID in the `DataGridView` is not anymore in the scanner range I paint it with white color. 
My problem is that with small lapses of time the RFID is inserted more than once. 
I thought that it was for the threads in the timer, so I put a `lock` inside, but if I try to scan in lapses smallers than 200 ms the problem still happening.

Is there a way to improve the code?

```
void tmrRepeatedScan_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                lock (thisLock)
                {
                    var detectedTags = serialPort.Scan(true, false, true, false);

                    foreach (var tag in detectedTags)
                    {
                        bool tagFound = false;
                        string TID = Regex.Replace(Conversions.ByteToHexadecimal(tag.GetTagId()), "(.{2})(?!$)", "$0-");
                        string EPC = Regex.Replace(Conversions.ByteToHexadecimal(tag.GetEpc()), "(.{2})(?!$)", "$0-");

                        if (!tagsReaded.Contains(TID))
                        {
                            tagsReaded.Add(TID);
                        }

                        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvTags.Rows)
                        {
                            if (row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Equals(TID))
                            {
                                row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
                                tagFound = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        if (!tagFound)
                        {
                            dgvTags.BeginInvoke(new InvokeDelegate(() => AddRow(TID, EPC)));
                        }
                    }
                }

                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvTags.Rows)
                {
                    if (!tagsReaded.Contains(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString()))
                    {
                        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvTags.Rows)
                {
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
                }
            }
        }
```

Sorry if my english is not very good.

Comment: BeginInvoke is an `async` operation. Try using Invoke instead to see if it solves the duplication issue.

Comment: That solves the duplication problem, than kyou!

Comment: but if I set a small lapse like 50 ms, it turns too slow.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch it back to `BeginInvoke` but you need to include a check to see if your tag exists in `tagsReaded` before doing `AddRow`. Try this:

```
void tmrRepeatedScan_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            lock (thisLock)
            {
                var detectedTags = serialPort.Scan(true, false, true, false);

                foreach (var tag in detectedTags)
                {
                    bool tagFound = false;
                    string TID = Regex.Replace(Conversions.ByteToHexadecimal(tag.GetTagId()), "(.{2})(?!$)", "$0-");
                    string EPC = Regex.Replace(Conversions.ByteToHexadecimal(tag.GetEpc()), "(.{2})(?!$)", "$0-");

                    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvTags.Rows)
                    {
                        if (row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Equals(TID))
                        {
                            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
                            tagFound = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    bool isNewTag = !tagsReaded.Contains(TID);

                    if (!tagFound && isNewTag )
                    {
                        dgvTags.BeginInvoke(new InvokeDelegate(() => AddRow(TID, EPC)));
                    }

                    if (newTag)
                    {
                        tagsReaded.Add(TID);
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvTags.Rows)
            {
                if (!tagsReaded.Contains(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString()))
                {
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvTags.Rows)
            {
                row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
            }
        }
}
```